# Haskell Ambiguous type variable -- I'm lost?

Tags: haskell, mongodb

So, the idea is that I would take the following code used to run MongoDB queries in haskell

- Full Example: https://gist.github.com/1337864
- Intro to Haskell MongoDB Driver: https://github.com/TonyGen/mongoDB-haskell/blob/master/doc/Example.hs

  pipe <- runIOE $ connect $ host "127.0.0.1"
  let run action = access pipe master "testdb" action
  run $ delete $ select [] "mycollection"

And I would like to turn it into this, so that I can pretend that the run function is a "db", like in the normal mongo driver.

```
db <- connectDb "127.0.0.1" "testdb" 
db $ delete $ select [] "mycollection"
```

Here's the function I wrote to do it:

```
mdb :: (MonadIO m) => String -> String -> IO (Action m a -> m (Either Failure a))
mdb hostname dbname = do
    pipe <- runIOE $ connect $ host hostname
    return (access pipe master (pack dbname))
```

I got the type by leaving it untyped, then asking ghci what the type was. I barely understand it.

**So here's the question**

When I make my program have ONLY `db <- connectDb "127.0.0.1" "testdb"` and don't use it, it fails with this Ambiguous Type error:  https://gist.github.com/1337864 - How can I make it unambiguous? Is it a bad idea to make this kind of an abstraction? How would you do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always feel like answering these questions "this is because your type is ambiguous".  For example, if you were given a value:

```
MonadIO m => (Action m a -> m (Either Failure a))
```

And told the monad `m` is a *particular* monad (not just any one), can you tell which one it is?  No.

If you don't use the returned value in a context that makes it apparent to which Monad `m` belongs, then you need to give the compiler additional information:

```
db <- connectDB "127.0.0.1" "testdb" :: IO (Action IO a -> IO (Either Failure a))
```

Comment: Thanks! Also note that changing the signature of mdb works too. I didn't realize what I was saying with that type.

Comment: It would be nice if `MonadIO m => m` would default to `IO` in otherwise ambiguous cases.

Comment: @Dan Burton: there is `-fextended-default-rules` and a corresponding pragma for things like that. Check if there are defaults for `MonadIO`. I think such defaulting is evil - that's why it's off by default. One interesting example is defaulting of `Control.Applicative` to `IO`.

Comment: The only thing the extended default rules does is add `()` to the list of default types (so that it's now `()`, `Integer` and `Double`), and relax the restriction on which type classes can be defaulted. There is no defaulting to `IO`. The reason why it can appear to be is that when typing expressions in GHCi, it will first attempt to run it as an `IO a`. If that fails, it's evaluated and printed as usual. However, this only happens at the outermost level, so any ambiguous `Monad m => m` further down in the expression will not be defaulted.